# datagridview delete rows in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete rows from datagridview, when the user selects any row and clicks on delete button , it should ask the user whether he wants to delete the rows?

I am able to delete the rows but I am not sure my control doesnot come to method below:

```
private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender,DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult usersChoice =
    MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the selected signs?\r\n" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count + " signs will be deleted!", "Signs", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    // cancel the delete event
    if (usersChoice == DialogResult.Cancel)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

I am not sure what show I write in my code so that when user clicks delete button the control comes to the above logic.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `my control doesnot come to method`  `control doesnot come to above logic`. what does control comes mean?

Comment: You are not sure if the above code is being executed?

Comment: I mean...the rows are deleted but it never asks user whether"Are you sure you want to delete the selected signs?\r\n""

Comment: Assuming you have actually registered this with the `UserDeletingRow`, its probably related to something else you are doing.  Can you post all the code that pertains to the `DataGridView`.  Note, if you create an empty project and just register for this event is seems to work just fine.

Comment: where is `dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow` being called from?

Comment: This is what I am not sure how or where to call the dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow.

Comment: Why don't you ask the question when the user clicks the delete button (i.e. in the delete button event handler) ?

Comment: @digEmAll this is what his eventhandler is, just that its not registered properly (or instantiated)

Comment: @nawal: no, UserDeletingRow is a datagridview event, I meant the button.Click event. Anyway, the question is solved now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register for this event in the Constructor of your `Form`.

For example:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponents();
   dataGridView1.UserDeletingRow += dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem too. The event handler was bound and got called but the "Selected" collection was empty.

To fix it, I had to change the grid's SelectionMode to "FullRowSelect".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the event is registered 
[image]

And then implement the event:

```
private void DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult response = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Delete row?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
   if ((response == DialogResult.No))
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```